# @react-pdf/renderer. How to generate PDF and download it

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I managed to generate the pdf document and show it on the page but I am struggling to setup an option to download it.

It is possible to setup something like click here to download the document?

Please refer to the code below:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { PDFViewer } from '@react-pdf/renderer';
import FeeAcceptance from '../Pdfgenerator/FeeAcceptance'

class AcceptFees extends Component {

  render () {
      return (
          <>
              <PDFViewer>
                  <FeeAcceptance member_detail={'test'} />
              </PDFViewer >

              <h1>click<a href="?????"> here </a>to download the document</h1>
          </>
      );
  }
}

export default AcceptFees;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In case you face the same problem, I found something that help.
Replace PDFViewer for the code below:

```
<PDFDownloadLink document={<FeeAcceptance />} fileName="fee_acceptance.pdf">
  {({ blob, url, loading, error }) => (loading ? 'Loading document...' : 'Download now!')}
</PDFDownloadLink>
```

https://react-pdf.org/components

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `ReactPDF.pdf`. here's a small code sample of an async function that returns a `url` (or even `blob` if the case requires !). We can use this `url` to download our PDF.

```
renderUrl = async() => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
const blob = await ReactPDF.pdf(<FeeAcceptance member_detail={'test'} />).toBlob()
const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
if(url && url.length>0){
    resolve(url)
  }
}
).then(res => res).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

To Download the generated `url` we can use the `download` attribute of `a` tag. Here's an example

```
let sampleTab = window.open()
if(sampleTab) {
  renderUrl().then(generatedUrl => {
    if( generatedUrl ){
      let aTag = document.createElement('a')
      aTag.href =  generatedUrl
      aTag.style = "display: none";
      aTag.download = 'FeeAcceptance.pdf'
      document.body.appendChild(aTag)
      aTag.click()
    } // else -> means something went wrong during pdf generation
  }).catch(err => console.log(err))
} // else -> means new tab can't be opened ... (some Adblock issue)
```